# Detox Test - Headless CI - Can't install generated apk in emulator

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I'm trying to set a local VM before creating an AWS EC5 machine for my CI to build and test my RN 0.68.2 application (expo ejected):

What's working:

- Build release APK (MacOS + Android Studio)
- Run tests (MacOS + Android Studio)
- Build release APK (VM Ubuntu 22.04 + commandlinetools)

What's not working:

- Run tests (VM Ubuntu 22.04 + commandlinetools)

It seems the script fails at installing the app in the emulator in the VM (See detox logs under)

I tried to use `--force-adb-install` but it did not fix the issue.

What could prevent `shell pm install` from installing the app in the emulator?

I can provide some `adb logcat` logs if needed.

Thanks for your help.

**Important parts of Detox logs:**

```
DEBUG: [EXEC_CMD, #16] "/home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-11072 shell "rm -fr /data/local/tmp/detox"
TRACE: [EXEC_SUCCESS, #16] 
DEBUG: [EXEC_CMD, #17] "/home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-11072 shell "mkdir -p /data/local/tmp/detox"
TRACE: [EXEC_SUCCESS, #17] 
DEBUG: [EXEC_CMD, #18] "/home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb" -s emulator-11072 push "/home/ME/repo/myapp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk" "/data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk"
TRACE: [EXEC_SUCCESS, #18] /home/ME/repo/myapp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 14.6 MB/s (42158675 bytes in 2.763s)

DEBUG: [SPAWN_CMD, #19, cpid=39601] /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk
DEBUG: [SPAWN_END, #19, cpid=39601] /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk terminated with SIGTERM
TRACE: [SPAWN_TRY_FAIL, #19] 
DEBUG: [SPAWN_CMD, #19, cpid=39614] (Retry #1) /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk
DEBUG: [SPAWN_END, #19, cpid=39614] /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk terminated with SIGTERM
TRACE: [SPAWN_TRY_FAIL, #19] 
DEBUG: [SPAWN_CMD, #19, cpid=39623] (Retry #2) /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk
DEBUG: [SPAWN_END, #19, cpid=39623] /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk terminated with SIGTERM
TRACE: [SPAWN_TRY_FAIL, #19] 
DEBUG: [SPAWN_CMD, #19, cpid=39658] (Retry #3) /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk
DEBUG: [SPAWN_END, #19, cpid=39658] /home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk terminated with SIGTERM
ERROR: ChildProcessError: `/home/ME/android/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-11072 shell pm install -r -g -t /data/local/tmp/detox/Application.apk` failed with code null
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/ME/repo/myapp/node_modules/child-process-promise/lib/index.js:132:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
```

**Edit 1**

Some specs :

- Ubuntu Live Server 22.04 x64 (So WITHOUT GUI)
- Node 14.19.3 + Yarn
- Emulator Package : 'system-images;android-28;default;x86_64'
- Emulator version : 31.2.10.0
- Platform tools version : Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
  Version 33.0.2-8557947
- Emulator device : pixel_4_xl
- Detox 19.7.1 + jest 26.6.3

**Edit 2**

I tried using another package (API29) for Pixel 4 XL as it runs on Android Q (API29), and tried to use API28 package with a pixel, nothing changed.

**Edit 3**

WEll, I ended up on [this issue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3342). As the only AOSP package available through sdkmanager is the API 30, I gave it a try. And it failed... BUT, this issue also mentions that something is going wrong when the emulator is not launched prior to launching the tests. So as I saw the emulator having a hard time launching, I ctl+c the process and run it again... AND IT WORKED.

**Conclusion**

So, while waiting for the Detox team to fix these issues, this is what I ended up with :

- Use AOSP package
- Don't use `--cleanup` as it rises an error at the end even if the test passes ([this issue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3439) - it happened to me locally)
- Launch the emulator before running the detox test command.